# MvxListView in Android with MvvmCross

Tags: android, android-listview, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross v3 and I have a little problem with list in Android.

I actually have a Mvx.MvxListView who works well, but I'm working on tablet, and ListView is a little bit inapropriate. So I want to have a control like WrapPannel in XAML to have more than one item in a row.

How can I have this kind of control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two challenges here:

#### 1. Find or make the control you want

The first is really up to you and your UX/design team to do - although people might be able to suggest apps and projects which might help. When choosing a control always be careful to understand it's memory use - especially:

- whether it virtualises the UI reusing cells (like a list does)
- or whether it creates a cell for every item even if the item is not visible (like a SL WrapPanel does?)

#### 2. Add data-binding to it

This second step is generally quite simple to do - take a look at one of the Mvx layout controls and see how it is converted for databinding - e.g. https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxLinearLayout.cs

You can generally just cut-and-paste this code over to your new type.

For more on subclassing existing types, also see N=18 in the video series - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n18-android-custom-controls-n1-days-of.html - this shows subclassing of a `TextView`

---

For a wrappanel, I did previously adapt and use one of @CheeseBaron's ports - FlowLayout - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/an-mono-for-android-wrappanelflowlayout.html. However, this has not been updated for v3 - if you do update it, it'd be great if you shared the results back.

Comment: Thanks so much, I merged the @CheeseBaron's ports with your code of Linear Layout and it works ! (I changed just few lines) I'm sorry but, what's the best way to share to you the new version of the BindingFlowLayout. I have done a mini project to test it, maybe I can upload it on my GitHub ? 
Edit: Maybe I talked too fast, I have a problem, as soon I update my ObservableCollection my items are displayed two times.
I will see that and I come back to you.