# Stack items horizontally in mvvmcross

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have to stack some items horizontally on the screen, for that I use `MvxLinearLayout`. Since `LinearLayout` does not have the ability to wrapp items `MvxLinearLayout` lacks it also. So I wonder if there is any control or any way that I can use to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you upload a sketch of how you want to arrange the items on the screen? That would be helpful in answering the question.

Comment: It's plain simpe. If there's 7 items in ItemSource and screen can fit horizontaly only 5 items I want control to show 5 items in first row and 2 items in second (I prefere it centered).

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040923/mvxlistview-in-android-with-mvvmcross

Comment: Thanx, Stuart. That's what I need. But unfortunately I've been around only on MvvmCross v3. So it's a bit out of my reach to translate this code. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: OK, I did it. It wasn't so difficult after all. I just copied code from MvxLinearLayout v3 into BindingFlowLayout. Thanks again Stuart  for your help and thanks for exceptional video tutorials. Also I would like to thank the rest of the guys.. i'll try to be more descriptive in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Linear Layout has the ability you need I believe. What I normally do for this situation is nest layouts. LinearLayout has a orientation property, So if you nest horizontal LinearLayout inside of a vertical LinearLayout you can create your desired effect.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: This should help you a little bit. Note how he uses a horizontal inside of a vertical. http://ryanmclaren.com/home/android-nested-linearlayout-example/

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help me. First of all: i don't know how many items will be in ItemsSource. It can be 2,3 or 12. So I cannot force my screen to split in "n" equaly width parts like example shows it with buttons. If you delete weight properties from buttons in this example and force first button to be in single line and put text in it that's large enough - you will have the same problem I0m experiencing - last two buttons will not show because linearlayout is not able to wrap them.

Comment: Oh, lol well put that in your question silly. I think gridview is likely a better option then.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to surround your MvxLinearLayout with HorizontalScrollView tag.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Mvx.MvxLinearLayout .../>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't want to scroll. It seems pointless to use scrollbar if there's plenty of space on the screen.

Comment: You can try GridView, which does have wrapping capabilities. Mvx.MvxGridView